# i would like to add to an embedded google map a share button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to share a google map direction with markers, i was looking to see if it was possible using google+ but couldn't find any reference.

[i'm not trying to share my location!]

my need is simple, share a map with directions and markers to different users.

my web application is asp .net using google maps API over javascript.

Comment: While it's an interesting idea, I don't think Google Maps allows this. Yet, you can create an tiny app that serves over `.io` domain. Great idea!